# Do i need to compile my SCSS files within my react.js project with the live SASS compiler? or does React.js this for me out of the box?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

so i am quiet new to react.js and i was using Sass & scss in my php projects.
there i would compile with the VScode extention 'Live Sass Compiler'.
Now i am using React.js and i dont know if i sould compile the written Sass with the extention from vs code or if react.js does this for me. react is reading my scss even without compiling to css.
but i cant help thinking that its better to let the LIVE SASS COMPILER do its work becouse it is awesome at creating browser compatible css.

does react.js autocompile SCSS just like the Live SASS compiler?

Comment: No, React does not compile SCSS to CSS. But many React projects are setup to use webpack as a build tool, which is regularly used together with sass-loader to compile SCSS to CSS. So you have to inspect your project setup to see how it's working on your end.

Comment: If you are using any build system to compile and run your project then the recommended way would be to use npm package to compile scss to css on the fly. One such package is node-sass.
If you are looking for boilerplate setup which can help you get up and running quickly without getting too much into setup then create-react-app is recommended. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app